# How to make Eclipse jump back automatically to development prespective when app that was debugged finished?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to make Eclipse jump back automatically to development prespective when app that was debugged finished executing? (like Visual Studio does)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think standard eclipse platform ships with this feature/option.

what you could do is

- click the right perspective button **MANUALLY** ,
- define a short-cut for openning your 'development perspective' and press that key combination **MANUALLY**. this could be done in preference->keys
- press ctrl-F8 (default bound) and select the right perspective
  **MANUALLY**.
- write your own plugin to switch perspective. of course,"**MANUALLY**"
  too.

Comment: I'd add that if using the ctrl-f8 which switches to the next perspective, you can also use Ctrl_shift+f8 to move to the previous perspective.